# Best way to fetch last 4 rows from a result set using mysql

Tags: sql, mysql, sql-order-by

Can any one please let me know, that, i need to fetch last 4 rows from a result-set using mysql. The result-set returns totally 6 records.

but, i need the records to be fetch from last4...i.e,

```
Record-3
Record-4
Record-5
Record-6
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To get the last *x* number of rows, but have them returned in ascending order, use:

```
  SELECT x.value
    FROM (SELECT y.value
            FROM TABLE y
        ORDER BY y.value DESC
           LIMIT 4) x
ORDER BY x.value
```

The answer requires that you create a derived table (AKA inline view) based on the rows you want.  Then the outer query re-orders the values for presentation.

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT * FROM tablename ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,4
```

will give you the last 4 records ("last" when you order the table by `id` which is supposed to be an auto-increment field here.)

Comment: I need the record-set results should be in ASCENDING order. What to do?

Comment: @PHP actually, then I don't know a solution that doesn't need counting the number of rows first in a separate operation. It would then e.g. be `SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY id LIMIT 656,4` when it has 660 rows.

Answer (score 0):

If you how that there is always 6 rows you could use limit.

```
SELECT * FROM Tabel LIMIT 2, 4
```