# "Order by desc" in reverse order?

Tags: php, sql, mysql, sql-order-by

Welcome,

I'm wondering is it possible to reverse returned data in sorting "order by desc" but i want that data in reverse order.

For example, i got table with values

```
ID
1
2
3
4
```

And i do

Order by ID ASC LIMIT 3
I got

```
1
2
3
```

When i do Order by ID DESC limit 3
i get

```
4
3
2
```

I would like to have

```
3
2
1
```

So i would like to order by ASC but revers results.
I was always doing this in PHP side using array_reverse, but today i want ask You.
Maybye i'm wrong and i can do this just in Mysql.
Regards

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to fetch last 4 rows from a result set using mysql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2980220/best-way-to-fetch-last-4-rows-from-a-result-set-using-mysql)

Answer (score 25):

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
  SELECT ... 
  FROM ... 
  ORDER BY ID ASC 
  LIMIT 3
) AS sq 
ORDER BY ID DESC
```

Think of it as working in two steps. First it executes the inner query: selects 3 records with lowest IDs. Then in the outer query it sorts them in descending order.

Comment: Dude, you are awesome!

Comment: How does this query work! Can you please explain or provide a link to this

Comment: Think of it as working in two steps. First it executes the inner query: selects 3 records with lowest IDs. Then in the outer query it sorts them in descending order.

Comment: Saved my day :)

Comment: @Ingus Graholskis glad this still helps :)

Answer (score 5):

You can fetch the first three rows using a subquery and then reverse the order of these rows in an outer query:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT *
    FROM yourtable
    ORDER BY ID
    LIMIT 3
) T1
ORDER BY ID DESC
```

Answer (score 4):

Nope, you aren't wrong. There are no difference for any sensible amount of data. Array_reverse is all right.
That's not a thing you have to be concerned too much of. Just use whatever you like more - for readability or other subjective reasons

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with a sub query :

```
SELECT * FROM
    (SELECT * FROM myTable ORDER BY idMyTable LIMIT 0, 3) AS r
ORDER BY r.idMyTable DESC
```

---

**Resources :**

- [Mysql - Subqueries](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/subqueries_part_1.html)

Comment: Resource page not found :(

Answer (score 0):

You could use an outer `SELECT` to reverse the order:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT …
    ORDER BY id ASC
    LIMIT 3
) sub
ORDER BY id DESC
```